# Reverter uma linha do standard input em C

Tags: c

Estou tentando obter o seguinte output caso o 
imput seja: oi mae
o output sera: eam io

o codigo que eu fiz, tentando treinar recursao foi:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse(char *arr)
{
    if (*arr != EOF)
        reverse((arr + 1));
    printf("%c", *arr);
}

int main()
{
    char input;

    scanf("%s[^\n]", &input);
    reverse(&input);
    return (0);
}
```

funciona para a primeira palavra, mas devolve um resultado estranho apos dar um espaco;

Alguem sabe me explicar porque?

Answer (score 0):

O que lhe impede de ler as duas palavras que são escritas é o `scanf` que está feito como:

```
%s[^\n]
```

Quando devia ser:

```
%[^\n]s
```

Mas tem vários outros pormenores que não estão certos:

- Você tem de ler uma string (`%s`) para um array de `char` e não um `char` simples (uma letra).
- O teste de fim de string tem de ser feito com `\0` ou `0` e não `EOF`.
- Está a mostrar o caratere na consola, mesmo que já seja o ultimo (o `'\0'`).

Corrigindo tudo isso o seu código fica assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse(char *arr)
{
    if (*arr != '\0'){ //testa o fim com '\0'
        reverse(arr + 1); 
        printf("%c", *arr); //só mostra se não for \0
    }
}

int main()
{
    char input[30]; //agora string em vez de char

    scanf("%29[^\n]s", input); //formato correto
    reverse(input); //sem o &
    return 0;
}
```

[Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/dRxjcy)

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado, se me permitir, gostaria de fazer algumas perguntas. Porque no input voce nao precisa passar com o simbolo &? o que representa o %29 antes do [^\n]s ?

Comment: @Piero Não precisa de passar o `&` porque o array de `char` funciona como se já fosse um ponteiro. Tem o `%29` para garantir que só le 29 carateres da entrada para o array pois tem de reservar um para o terminador. Se lesse mais que 29 já estaria a sobrepor memoria que não era sua.